aks terraform azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control options
I'm using azurerm v4 and want to manage AKS access with entra roles.  In my terraform I have this block:
// I create an AD group...
resource "azuread_group" "aks_admins" {
  display_name     = "aks-${var.sub} admins"
  security_enabled = true
  description      = "used to manage access to the ${var.sub} aks cluster"
}

// then I create a cluster...
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "this" {

  ... other settings...

  azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control {
    azure_rbac_enabled = true
    // what does this next bit actually do????
    admin_group_object_ids = [
      azuread_group.aks_admins.object_id
    ] 
  }
}

docs say

admin_group_object_ids - (Optional) A list of Object IDs of Azure Active Directory Groups which should have Admin Role on the Cluster.

what does "which should have Admin Role on the Cluster." actually mean?  Do I need to manually add that group as a "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role" to my cluster IAM?
what value do I gain by setting that value?

My understanding is: you can set the cluster admins using admin_group_object_ids property. I'm not sure if I made myself understood?

creating admin_group_object_ids automatically grants the specified Azure AD group the "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin" role on the AKS cluster, so I think you dont need to manually assign it in IAM @Jason


aks terraform azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control options

If you use EntraID role we should use the necessary permisson to assign the role to the group by following the EntraID doc and befor assigning make sure you have following permission Microsoftdoc.


Demo Configuration:
resource "azuread_group" "aks_admins" {
  display_name       = var.admin_group_name
  security_enabled   = true
  assignable_to_role = true
  description        = "Admin group for managing the AKS cluster"
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "group_members" {
  for_each = toset(var.user_object_ids)

  group_object_id  = azuread_group.aks_admins.object_id
  member_object_id = each.value
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "reader_role" {
  scope                = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader" # Assigning Reader role to the group
  principal_id         = azuread_group.aks_admins.object_id
}


resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = var.aks_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "${var.aks_name}-dns"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    vm_size    = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    node_count = 2
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control {
    azure_rbac_enabled = true
    admin_group_object_ids = [
      azuread_group.aks_admins.object_id
    ]
  }
}

Deployment:



Refer:
azuread_group | Resources | hashicorp/azuread | Terraform | Terraform Registry

now I'm only more confused!  you said creating admin_group_object_ids automatically grants the specified Azure AD group the "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin" role on the AKS cluster, so I think you dont need to manually assign it in IAM  But that's exactly what DID NOT happen.
In your example, you create a group, add users to the group, and then assign the group to a role on the cluster (BTW, why would I give READ to the cluster admins?).  if you already explicitly assigned the group to a role, what value does setting admin_group_object_ids have????
